# How to check all Magento 2 versions available to install via Composer?

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer

I work with different projects using Magento 2.1, 2.2 and 2.3, I'd like to update each project to the last version available of each release, for example:

**Magento 2.2.4 -> Magento 2.2.11**

How could I check all the releases available via terminal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to run these commands below to check the full list of all the releases available:

**Magento Open Source:**

```
composer show magento/product-community-edition --all | grep -m 1 versions
```

**Magento Commerce:**

```
composer show magento/product-enterprise-edition --all | grep -m 1 versions
```

[image: Magento 2 all releases via terminal]

Comment: As enhancement regarding the question, filter the versions by piping the result to eg.  `grep -oP '2.2.[0-9][\w-]*'`